# Kibana Custom Filter ,How to create Regex to eliminate all terms with numeric values

Tags: regex, kibana

I have a list of request coming in based on free text searches or codes.
I would like to eliminate the code-like requests, and only keep the natural language request.
Therefore I would need a query that can separate those terms.

Below is the query-json I already tried

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "q": "[^\d\W]"}
  }
}
}
```

error I get is "Bad String" for the following line "q": "[^\d\W]"}
Expected would be to improve the regex in order to be able to keep the relevant data

Comment: What is a "natural language request"? How can you describe it in terms of regex patterns?

Comment: If you want to match any string but a string consisting of only digits, try `"q": "[^0-9]+"}`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, didn't think it could be that simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"regexp": {
      "q": "[^0-9]+"}
}
```

The Lucene regex engine used in Kibana anchors all patterns by default, so `[^0-9]+` will match any string, from start to end of which there are only characters other than digits.

Moreover, `\d` and `\W` and other shorthand character classes are not supported either.